# anguilarui - uiDate - datepicker does not select date after option update

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui

I have a problem with angular-ui uiDate directive.
The datepicker stops working after i try to update min/maxDate options in controller.

http://plnkr.co/edit/H6KaES?p=preview

What must be done to fix that ?

Thank You!

Comment: Think you're gonna have to use the non-minified version of these js dependencies so you can step through the code some more and see what's breaking (unless it's a known issue someone else is aware of)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like this is a bug with the most recent version.  I loaded an [earlier version](https://raw.github.com/angular-ui/ui-date/f7dcac8378b3298d1280ff7ab6121646c76ad509/src/date.js) and it seems to work.  I also swapped your `minDate/maxDate` properties.

I would suggest filing a bug report with the ui team.

Side note - I prefer the [angular-ui bootstrap datepicker](http://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/#/datepicker) myself, but that's just personal preference.

[Here's the fixed plunk](http://plnkr.co/edit/t2YRMo?p=preview)

Comment: thx for reply. it seems this bug already reported to angular-ui. https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-date/issues/19